# How to Slide right to left JQuery HTML CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slide

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#One").click(function() {
    $("#Two").animate({
      width: 'toggle'
    }, -10);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-
    3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script src="http://jquery-
    ui.googlecode.com/svn/tags/latest/ui/jquery.effects.core.js"></script>
<script src="http://jquery-
    ui.googlecode.com/svn/tags/latest/ui/jquery.effects.slide.js">
</script>
<script>
</script>

<div id="One" style="width:50px;height:200px;background-
     color:yellow;position:relative;top:300px;left:600px;">One</div>
<div id="Two" style="width:200px;height:200px;background-
    color:black;position:relative;top:100px;left:400px;">Two</div>
```

Above is the code, my problem exactly is that I can't get it to slide normally. When I click on it it disappears then comes back on the second click. I just want it to slide normally.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this::

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#One").click(function() {
    $("#Two").animate({
      left: '400px'
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: implemented the code. It's not working at all. Worse than before.

Comment: It will work, but I am confused with your requirement now. Just send the fiddle link/code link and I can make sure to solve it asap.

Comment: If you remove the '-' from the code you'll get a toggle slide that you'll see from left to right. Now I want the same thing except from right to left. The code you gave (thank you) is buggy. If you can figure out how to get that right what I asked I would really appreciate it.